# Wordpress comments order with wp_list_comments()

Tags: wordpress

According to Codex:

> Setting 'reverse_top_level' to true will display the most recent comment first then going back in order, and setting this to false will show the oldest comments first. If not specified, it will use the value stored in the WordPress dashboard settings.

My code:

```
    $comments = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->comments WHERE comment_post_ID = $comments_post_id AND comment_approved=1 ORDER BY comment_date DESC LIMIT $comments_per_page OFFSET $offset" );

    wp_list_comments(array(
         'reverse_top_level' => false,
         'type' => 'comment',
         'callback' => 'render_user_comment',
         'style' => 'div'
    ), $comments);
```

But it just does not work. Whatever I do. I played with ORDER BY and WP Discussion Settings. Only if I set 'reverse_top_level' to *false*, WP always displays the most recent comments first.

Did anybody face this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you are not using get_comments( $args )? You could then just set the correct parameters to achieve what you are after.

Comment: @OrlandoP. No specific reason, I just prefer to work with DB. As for my issue, it does not matter, whether I use get_comments() or $wpdb->get_results. The same strange behavior for 'reverse_top_level'. I set it to false to get the desired order, but I am very careful about using something that contradicts the official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like.

```
$args = array(
   'post_id' => $comments_post_id,
   'status' => 'approve',
   'orderby' => 'comment_date',
   'order' => 'DESC',
   'number' => $comments_per_page,
   'offset' => $offset
);

//get the comments
$comments = get_comments( $args  );
```